# Java: Lombok and unwrapping properties

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, lombok

I am working with JavaFx properties and Lombok

I started recently using Lombok, it makes my code much simpler and readable, but I have the issue with JavaFx properties, it doesn't unwrap them like I would generate them with IntelliJ I get a getter for the property itself and a getter for the value. Here is a simple example with explanation what I want to do.

```
public class LombokAndProperties {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();

        model.getStringProperty(); // returns the StringProperty instead of String
        model.stringProperty(); // doesn't exist -> doesn't compile

        // Expectation:
        // model.getStringProperty() <- return the String that is stringProperty.get()
        // model.stringProperty() <- return the StringProperty itself
    }


    @Getter
    private static class Model{

        private StringProperty stringProperty;

    }

}
```

I know that I can use like: `model.getStringProperty().get()` to obtain the `String` value, but I would prefer the direct way if it exists.

Does any solution exist for this?

Comment: The syntax in getStringProperty() is standard for getter methods. It has nothing to do with the .get() method which you have, typically, on optionals. I recommend you just stick with the model.getStringProperty().get() syntax.

Comment: I thought maybe there is a way like at validations using something like: `@UnwrapValidatedValue`

Comment: There has been some discussions on adding a special javafx annotation to lombok, see https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1222. However, it looks like this is not a top priority for the maintainers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way:

```
public class LombokAndProperties {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();

        model.getStringProperty(); // <- return the String that is stringProperty.getStringProperty()
        model.stringProperty(); // <- return the StringProperty itself

    }



    private static class Model{

        private interface DelegateExample {
            String getStringProperty();
        }

        @Accessors(fluent = true)
        @Getter
        @Delegate(types = DelegateExample.class)
        private StringProperty stringProperty = new StringProperty();

    }

    private static class StringProperty {
        String property = "p";

        public String getStringProperty(){
            return property;
        }
    }
}
```

With `@Accessor` annotation you can manipulate your getter name, while `@Delegate` gives you a delegation pattern. You can find more [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) and [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate). However notice two things: first, those annotations are marked as "experimental" by Lombok team. Second, to me this is a quite confusing API, so use it carefully.

If this solution is too complicated, I would suggest to adopt only `@Accessor` and creating your own delegate method:

```
public class LombokAndProperties {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();

        model.getStringProperty(); // <- return the String that is stringProperty.get()
        model.stringProperty(); // <- return the StringProperty itself

    }

    private static class Model{

        @Accessors(fluent = true)
        @Getter
        private StringProperty stringProperty;

        public String getStringProperty(){
            return stringProperty.get();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm...nice trick but this is not so dynamic, I have to create  separate interface for every single Model I have. Another minus is this makes the code even more complicated instead of simplifying it.

Comment: It is exaclty what I mean when I said that it is quite confusing. I would suggest you to use `@Accessor` annotation for having a working `model.stringProperty()` and creating your own delegate for method `model.getStringProperty()`. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Yeah... that would make more sense, than overcomplicating :D

Comment: Thanks, I think I would accept your answer since you did a research and an attempted to give an appropriate answer even if it is not the truly expected answer. Hoping as @Jan Rieke commented, they will add a support for jfx properties then I can use them instead of this.